# How to change a string content according to another string with LINQ C#

Tags: c#, string, linq, stringbuilder

In my homework, I've got a mission to replicate the enigma machine.
so I'm building the reflector part.
The reflector has a configuration like this:

> YRUHQSLDPXNGOKMIEBFZCWVJAT

and the task is for every character in a string,
I need to replace it with the corresponding character in the configuration position,
assuming the text would contain only uppercase letters.
for example, let's say I've got an input like this:

> ABCXYZ

so the answer would be 
"YRUJAT"

so I made a function like this:

```
public string GetReflectedString(string msg)
{
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char item in msg)
    {
        answer.Append(m_configuration[Helper.ABC.IndexOf(item.ToString().ToUpper())]);
    }
    return answer.ToString();
}
```

but I have the feeling this could be made better with LINQ functions.
can anybody help?

Comment: Better in what why? Linq is not magic. I agree it forms nice code but it doesn't do much more than lazy loading and nice method chaining (for when in memory at least)

Comment: @GiladGreen I can't help but notice that you attribute complex features of EF/Linq2SQL/nHibernate to Linq. Linq is not magic, its just an API/set of interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd not use the words *better* necessarily but maybe uses less lines of code, here is an implementation using linq:

```
var result = new string(msg.Select(c => m_configuration[Helper.ABC.IndexOf(c)]).ToArray());
```

Badically, replace the `foreach` with a projection (`.Select`) and then place all of it as an input for the `string` constructor.

As a short standalone example:

```
var configuration = "YRUHQSLDPXNGOKMIEBFZCWVJAT";
var abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

var input = "ABCXYZ";
var result = new string(input.Select(c => configuration[abc.IndexOf(c)]).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);    // YRUJAT
```

Comment: Yes, Exactly what I was looking for
would you use the LINQ or the foreach?

Comment: @DorLugasi - I'd go for the linq as I like the way it looks. I just wanted to emphasise that it isn't much different than what you have shown in the question.

Comment: yes, I know the functionality behind is the same.
I like the LINQ better, that's why I asked, maybe I should have explained myself better.
 anyway, thank you for your help